# Moving next observation to previous column to make a triangle in sas

Tags: sas

I able to populate the input and now want to convert the below input triangle to right angle triangle as show in the output.

INPUT

```
asur    C0012   C0112   C0212   C0312   C0412   C0512
2000    5133049 2629201 3145968 3710712 4023650 4090428
2001        1413328 2535620 2348286 3357177 3389958
2002            1594953 2663058 3003008 3139910
2003                1694882 3616471 4201837
2004                    1861858 3567559
2005                        17853454
2006                         
2007
```

OUTPUT

```
asur    C0012   C0112   C0212   C0312   C0412   C0512
2000    5133049 2629201 3145968 3710712 4023650 4090428
2001    1413328 2535620 2348286 3357177 3389958  
2002    1594953 2663058 3003008 3139910      
2003    1694882 3616471 4201837          
2004    1861858 3567559              
2005    1785345                      
2006                         
2007
```

Comment: can you post the actual current and expected in a code block, or at a minimum replace the two separate images with a single one showing both current and expected ?  What should happen to the far right side columns when the leftward shift occurs ? Should they be unchanged or set to a missing or zero value ?

Comment: Expected output is a bit off still...

Comment: You also need to include what you've tried so far. If you need help with an approach, you likely need an array.  
You can use CALL SORTC/SORTN on the array and then reverse it using an array or reverse the names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show what was tried, otherwise we are just doing your homework.

```
data have;
input 
asur    C0012   C0112   C0212   C0312   C0412   C0512;
datalines;
2000    5133049 2629201 3145968 3710712 4023650 4090428
2001    .       1413328 2535620 2348286 3357177 3389958
2002    .       .       1594953 2663058 3003008 3139910
2003    .       .       .       1694882 3616471 4201837
2004    .       .       .       .       1861858 3567559
2005    .       .       .       .       .       17853454
run;
```

Use an ARRAY statement to allow indexed address processing of the variables. i and j track which slots the values move from and to.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array C C0012 C0112 C0212 C0312 C0412 C0512;

  j = 0;
  if _n_ > 1 then 
    do i = _n_ to dim(c);  * source slot: start on the diagonal;
      j = j + 1;           * target slot: iteration #;
      C[j] =  C[i];        * shift data leftward;
      C[i] = . ;           * clear slot data was in;
    end;

  drop i j ;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. I didn't work on Array and no idea to create array.